# z3prover, how to randomize in c++

Tags: c++, z3

when in python, i can use

```
z3.set_param('auto_config', False,
         'smt.phase_selection', 5,
         'smt.arith.random_initial_value', True,
         'smt.random_seed', np.random.randint(0, 655350),
         'sat.phase', 'random',
         'sat.random_seed', np.random.randint(0, 655350))
```

to get things work. Whereas in c++, the job is never done. I tried to set params with `solver.set()`, as well as using `Z3_global_param_set`. For boolean problems, I can only get the same model.
What i want to do is to randomize every first outcome of the model for the same solver. Randomizing the result means a lot to my current work. Can any one help me? Thanks a lot!

In short, I want to get randomized result for a problem every time i call `solver.get_model()`, for problems such as (in boolean)

```
if(b0, 1, 0)+if(b1, 1, 0)+if(b2, 1, 0)>1
```

Thanks again for reading my description.

Comment: Start reading here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Thank you  for your reply, but I want to randomize z3's out come, Indeed I use c++'s random lib to set the seeds for z3. But never work (

Comment: @jiangqilei *as far as I know*, the random parameter affects the way in which the search proceeds *[thus affecting the performance]*, but that doesn't necessarily result in a *random model* *[depending on the structure of your formula]*. I guess you would be better off blocking previous model solutions and ask for new ones, in an incremental manner. Perhaps more experienced *z3* users can provide more accurate information.

Comment: solver.set and global parameter settings should work, so to understand what is not working I would benefit from a stand-alone repro. 
Notice that the set_param function from the C++ API calls into Z3_global_param_set. 
The python and C++ APIs call the same functions so it is the same code-path underneath.

Comment: @patrickTrentin Thank you. My teacher once told me the process underneath as you described. In python, we actually have got the random results. And yeah..., blocking previous models is also what i have implemented to get all solutions. Randomizing in python seems good. In c++, I think the problem is hidden somewhere in my code, deep yet obvious, i think... (crying face...

Comment: @NikolajBjorner Really the same? I once suspected that c++ and python are both wrappers, for, when looking at header files, the implementations are actually hidden. Python works, so I might stick with Python API, as the performance gained by language might be small.Thank you for your clarifies.

Comment: @jiangqilei as I said, i am not an expert of z3, so there's that. If you try the same formula for which it worked on python with the C++ API, does it work?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Saidly, no... it does not work, so i guess i just missed something, maybe the places to put these lines of code is not what i am guessing. Since Python works fine, so i think i should stick to Python API. May be what i do here is not what Z3 recommends (randomize the result every time). So I am quite satisfied that Python API works. Guessing that both languges are wrappers, i suppose the performance gained by switching languges is not that much. With these in mind, i think i should just leave c++ alone... Life is short, anyway.  Thank you for your time :)

Comment: uhmmmm, okay, well I learned something new today, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Z3_global_param_set("sat.phase", "random");
Z3_global_param_set("smt.phase-selection", "5");
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.